# Condition for a,b in common density $ax+by$

Tags: probability, integration, improper-integrals

> The common density of a couple is $f(x,y)=ax+by,\text{(0<x,y<1)}$.
>
> Which conditions should a and b satisfy?

About A: I'm almost sure the integral $\displaystyle{\iint f(x,y)dxdy}$ diverges: $$\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{1}f(x,y)dydx=\int_0^\infty axy+\frac b 2 y^2\mid_{y=1}-axy+\frac b 2 y^2\mid_{y=-\infty} dx\overset{?}{=}\infty$$. I'm almost sure I'm wrong but I don't know any other approches for solving this integral. This integral is defined iff a,b are zeroing but again I don't think that's what the question asked for.

How can I prove this integral converges?

Comment: " $0<x,y<1$" probably means " $0<x<1,\, 0<y<1$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $0<x, y< 1$ usually means that both $x$ and $y$ are in the open interval $(0, 1)$. With these domains, you get

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1(ax+by)dxdy&=1\Leftrightarrow\int_0^1\int_0^1bydxdy+\int_0^1\int_0^1axdxdy\\
&=b\left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_0^1+a\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^1\\
&=a+b\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
So $a$ and $b$ should satisfy the condition $a+b=1$.